# Ошибка при запуске hibernate приложения в eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate, eclipse, maven, main

```
  package hibernate;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

файл pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MavenHibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernateM</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId> maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>hibernate.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId> maven-copiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
</project>
```

class hibernateUtil

```
package hibernate;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class hibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    static {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(cfg.getProperties());

        sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

ошибка

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:118)
    at hibernate.hibernateUtil.<clinit>(hibernateUtil.java:12)
    at hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 6 more
```

теперь другая ошибка

```
янв. 04, 2018 1:01:34 ПП org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.12.Final}
янв. 04, 2018 1:01:34 ПП org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:244)
    at hibernate.hibernateUtil.<clinit>(hibernateUtil.java:12)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:122)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:276)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: и какая же ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

В Java 9 вынесли JAXB из стандартной библиотеки в модуль java.xml.bind. Либо используйте Java 8, либо придётся явно указать JVM на необходимость этого модуля. В Eclipse это можно сделать так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или добавить в pom.xml к зависимостям

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: ваш скриншот сделан в KDE или Gnome?